# Pandas Groupby from two csv files

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I'm doing an exercise from Datacamp that tells you to aggregate life expectancy by region from two files.

## life_fname with columns: ['Country', 'Life Expectancy']

Source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_1650/datasets/life_expectancy.csv

## regions_fname with columns: ['Country', 'Region']

Source:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_1650/datasets/regions.csv

```
# Read life_fname into a DataFrame: life
life = pd.read_csv(life_fname, index_col='Country')

# Read regions_fname into a DataFrame: regions
regions = pd.read_csv(regions_fname, index_col='Country')

# Group life by regions['region']: life_by_region
life_by_region = life.groupby(regions['region'])

print(life_by_region)
# Print the mean over the '2010' column of life_by_region
print(life_by_region['2010'].mean())
```

I understand what index_col does with one dataframe but what I don't understand is how does python know to find the 'common denominator' column ['Country'] across multiple dataframes?

I don't explicitly state:

life['Country'] == regions['Country'].

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is correct. Pandas/Python 100% does not infer that `life['Country'] == regions['Country']`. Someone correct me if I'm wrong (I'm not a pandas expert) but when you state `life.groupby(regions['region'])`, you're telling pandas to do 2 basic things:

**First**: Pandas sees that you want to groupby `regions['region']`. In order to do this, it maps all the indices for the `regions['region']` Series to whatever group they belong too.

**Second**: Pandas takes the mappings from indices to groups and applies them to the `life` Dataframe's index.

Why does this work? Sheer coincidence. The only only reason this works is because (a) your Dataframes are of the same length and (b) your indices for your Dataframes happen to coencide perfectly. So this groupby operation happens to work out but you should know that it's all by chance. If you want to actually do this in a sensible and reliable way, then you should merge the two Dataframes on `country` (or whatever is appropriate) and then perform a groupby. Hope this helps.

EDIT: Added example on how to correctly do this:

```
pd.merge(life, regions, how='left', left_index=True, 
         right_index=True).groupby('region')['2010'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

While this sort of grouping may seem dangerous and haphazard at first, it turns out to be rather well behaved.

The key here, is that when you pass a `Series` as a grouping object to `DataFrame.groupby()` it by default aligns the series on the indices. Typically, you would group a `DataFrame` by one of its own columns, in which case alignment on index is virtually guaranteed. But in this case, because both `DataFrames` have `country` as their index pandas appropriately aligns the values in `life` with the correct `region` and calculates the mean.

The two `DataFrames` can even be ordered differently, and can have a different number of total elements, and calculations will behave properly. The following three examples should illustrate this point:

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                    'val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'], 
                    'region': ['region1', 'region1', 'region2', 'region2', 'region2']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B'], 
                    'region': ['region1', 'region1', 'region2', 'region2']})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'Z'], 
                    'region': ['region1', 'region1', 'region2', 'region2', 'region2', 'region7']})
df1 = df1.set_index('Country')
df2 = df2.set_index('Country')
df3 = df3.set_index('Country')
df4 = df4.set_index('Country')
```

### Case 1:

Both DataFrames share the same indices, and are the same length, but they are not sorted in the same way.

```
df1.groupby(df2.region).mean()
#         val
#region      
#region1  4.5
#region2  2.0
```

Because the Series are first aligned on index, the average value of each region is still calculated correctly. `region1` contains `'E'` and `'D'` which have a value of `4` and `5`

### Case 2:

The grouping `DataFrame` is shorter in length and doesn't contain all of the countries in the `DataFrame` to be grouped

```
df1.groupby(df3.region).mean()
#         val
#region      
#region1  4.5
#region2  2.5
```

Again, the calculation works properly. `'A'` has no region, so it's no longer included, and the mean for each region is calculated properly.

### Case 3

The grouping `DataFrame` contains more groups than the `DataFrame` to be grouped

```
df1.groupby(df3.region).mean()
#         val
#region      
#region1  4.5
#region2  2.0
```

As the extra group doesn't align to anything in the grouped `DataFrame` it doesn't lead to any output.

Basically, the only thing that will cause an issue is if the index of the Series you are using to group with is duplicated. Then `pandas` cannot determine how to align the values properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
It is better to do group by after merging the data frame,it works 
well even index is not same.


 df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',"F"], 
                "life_expectency": [60, 70, 80, 50, 100,80]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'], 
                "region": ['region1', 'region1', 'region2', 
                           'region2', 'region2']})

pd.merge(df1,df2,how="left").groupby("region")[2010].mean()

note-taken same dataframes from ALollz answer.
```